# How Can I Shorten Javascript to Close (.popup) div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This javascript/jquery helps to close out a popup with a few different functions - clicking a div, pressing esc, or clicking outside the object. Is there a way to shorten this code? Or is there a better way to write it? Thanks!

```
$(function () {
    $('.ex').click(function () {
        $('.popup').removeClass('fadeIn').slideUp(1000);
        $('.blurme').removeClass('blur');
    });
});

$(document).on('keydown', function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 27) { // ESC
        $('.popup').removeClass('fadeIn').slideUp(1000);
        $('.blurme').removeClass('blur');
    }
});

$(document).click(function (e) {
    if (e.target.id != 'popup') {
        $('.popup').removeClass('fadeIn').slideUp(1000);
        $('.blurme').removeClass('blur');
    }
});
```

Comment: One option would be to have `function closePopup()` to contain the actual closing code, and just call that in your handler. Alternatively, if there's a "primary" handler (eg. close button) you could have the other events do `$('.ex').trigger('click');`

Comment: Since the action is always the same, you could create a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, factorise in a `closePopup()` function. You can also chain the `$(document).on(...).click(...)`

```
function closePopup() {
    $('.popup').removeClass('fadeIn').slideUp(1000);
    $('.blurme').removeClass('blur');
}

$(function () {
    $('.ex').click(closePopup);
});

$(document).on('keydown', function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 27) closePopup()
}).click(function (e) {
    if (e.target.id != 'popup') closePopup()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have very redondant code in your  functions :

**First create a function for the popup closing :**

```
var _closePopup = function (){
        $('.popup').removeClass('fadeIn').slideUp(1000);
        $('.blurme').removeClass('blur');
}
```

and call it in your function with `_closePopup()`

```
$(function () {
    $('.ex').click(function () {
        _closePopup()
    });
});

$(document).on('keydown', function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 27) { // ESC
        _closePopup()
    }
});

$(document).click(function (e) {
    if (e.target.id != 'popup') {
        _closePopup()
    }
});
```

Comment: You can shorten even more to `$('.ex').click(_closePopup)`

Comment: this is just a syntax to prevent having twice function calls. maybe it will confuse the owner question. But true; this can be minifiied that way.

Comment: Well, you just pass one function, instead of a function calling another function :)

Comment: Thanks for the advice! As you can see from my code, I am still learning a lot.

Comment: We all are, always.